# No reads mapped in proper pairs, in paired-end sequencing bamfile using samtools

Tags: alignment, genome, samtools

I am working with a bamfile of paired-end whole genome sequencing, and want to filter out reads from a specific genomic region that are not mapped in a  proper pair (these sometimes indicate a structural variant). I am using samtools, and tried to filter the reads with the "flag" option, to select for reads that are not mapped in a proper pair. If I'm correct, these reads should not have 2 in their flag value. 
(https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/explain-flags.html)

However, according to samtools none of my reads are mapped in a proper pair. When I count (-c) all the reads in the region I specified, without filter, it gives me a total count of 179:

```
samtools view input.bam "8:113483114-113483213"  -c

179
```

When I filter for reads that are properly paired, i.e. flag contains "2" (-f 2), the count is zero:

```
samtools view input.bam "8:113483114-113483213"  -f 2 -c

0
```

I checked to see if the reads are recognized to be paired (-f 1), and if the mates are mapped (-F 8), and all of them are:

```
samtools view input.bam "8:113483114-113483213"  -f 1 -F 8  -c
179
```

I also tried for other regions in the genome and encounter the same problem everywhere. 
I checked the regions in IGV using the same BAM files, and IGV tells me most of the reads are properly paired, and only a few aren't. 
Does anyone know what is going on here? Were the BAM files flagged in a way that doesn't account for proper mate mapping?

Any help is welcome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Found the answer: turned out the aligner (BWA) was set in such a way that it never adds a properly paired flag. It can be fixed using ppflag-fixer:
https://github.com/mskcc/htstools